# response.write() in special position

Tags: asp.net

```
x:100
y:400
```

i like

```
response.write("test");
```

in

```
x,y special ;
```

in x:100 and y:400 write test on page

Comment: possible duplicate of [positioning the output of response.write in asp.net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742255/positioning-the-output-of-response-write-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: What you propose to do makes no sense, since the document your return through Response is just an html document. You should learn the basics of HTML and CSS to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A good way of doing it**

I see you want to write Test in the co-ordinate location.  You can do:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="TestPanel" visible="false">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" id="TestText" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
int x = 100;    // Your X coordinate
int y = 400;    // Your Y coordinate

// Set the text of the panel (your response.write in effect)
TestText.Text = "Testing!";

// Set the style of the containing panel to position it to X and Y
TestPanel.Style["position"] = "absolute";
TestPanel.Style["top"] = y.ToString() + "px";
TestPanel.Style["left"] = x.ToString() + "px";

// Make the panel visible
TestPanel.Visible = true;
```

**A quicker and dirtier method**

If you are determined to use response.write you can do:

```
int x = 400;
int y = 200;
Response.Write("<div style='position:absolute;top:" + y.ToString() + "px;left:" + x.ToString() + "px'>Testing!</div>");
```

Comment: It will work but html is not intended to be used as OP suggests. IMHO before to apply your solution OP should learn a bit about HTML / CSS to understand relative positionning and layout, there's no "grid" in html.